# URL ist to long change /href sytle

Tags: urls

my url's are to long. I want to trim them. I used /url{long url}. I found the /href{long url}{Description}, but the href looks different (no monospace font). How can i adapt the /url style to the /href style? Or is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

The `\nolinkurl` command typesets an URL without creating a link and with `\href` you can create the link. Combined, this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    % Original version:
    \url{http://www.myverylongurl.org/some/subpage}

    % Shortened URL:
    \href{http://www.myverylongurl.org/some/subpage}{\nolinkurl{http://www.myverylongurl.org/}}
\end{document}
```